# Pods with 0 targets and missing base SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, base-sdk

I just used Cocoapods to install the Stripe framework for my app. However, when I open the new file, the Pods project file reads, "0 targets, missing base SDK." And there's also a question mark next to it and the Podfile. How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly have you tried to fix this based on other SO questions?